# Format words in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, formatting, richtextbox

I am using the following code to find each line that starts with "@" and format it by making it bold:

```
foreach (var line in tweetText.Document.Blocks)
        {
            var text = new TextRange(line.ContentStart,
                           line.ContentEnd).Text;
            line.FontWeight = text.StartsWith("@") ?
                           FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal;
        }
```

However, I would like to use the code to find each word instead of line beginning with "@" so I could format a paragraph like:

> Blah blah blah **@username** blah blah blah blah **@anotherusername**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could probably use some optimization as I did it quick, but this should get you started

```
private void RichTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{    
     tweetText.TextChanged -= RichTextBox_TextChanged;
     int pos = tweetText.CaretPosition.GetOffsetToPosition(tweetText.Document.ContentEnd);

     foreach (Paragraph line in tweetText.Document.Blocks.ToList())
     {
        string text = new TextRange(line.ContentStart,line.ContentEnd).Text;

        line.Inlines.Clear();

        string[] wordSplit = text.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
        int count = 1;

        foreach (string word in wordSplit)
        {
            if (word.StartsWith("@"))
            {
                Run run = new Run(word);
                run.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                line.Inlines.Add(run);
            }
            else
            {
                line.Inlines.Add(word);
            }

            if (count++ != wordSplit.Length)
            {
                 line.Inlines.Add(" ");
            }
        }
     }

     tweetText.CaretPosition = tweetText.Document.ContentEnd.GetPositionAtOffset(-pos);
     tweetText.TextChanged += RichTextBox_TextChanged;
}
```

Comment: This caused an unhandled exception in the TextRange part. Please note this is being used in the richtextbox_textchanged event and is written in WPF

Comment: RichTextBox does not support ".Document.Blocks.ToList()"

Comment: [It has to...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.blockcollection.aspx) BlockCollection inherits from TextElementCollection which inherits IEnumerable<T>. Are you sure you're in WPF and using `System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox` and not `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox`?

Comment: `ToList` is an extension method from LINQ. Make sure you have a `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: Thanks Abe. However, when you run the code, the text is jumbled together (ignores space bar) and the text cursor is always at the start of the text. Any ideas?

Comment: The "ignores space bar" problem comes from the split, you have to re-add spaces before the closing bracket of the foreach loop (which you may have to replace by a regular for loop to add spaces only between words). For the cursor problem, you have to save the cursor position before the process and load it after. You may look at RichTextBox.CaretPosition or RichTextBox.Selection... (but good luck with that !)

Comment: @Rhys Updated the answer to include spaces. Where should the caret be positioned at?

Comment: Thanks Jim. Well at the moment, it is typing from right to left instead of the standard left to right. Could you please make it type left to right

Comment: One last thing Jim, if I was to click in the middle of a sentence to change something, it would move the caret to the end of the line. Perhaps could you make it remember the current caret position and just move it along one position?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your exact requirements, but I encourage you not to use a RichtextBox for Syntax-Highlighting purposes.
There is an excellent component called AvalonEdit that can easily used for this. You can read more about AvalonEdit in this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor

Syntaxdefinition for your requirement:

```
<SyntaxDefinition name="customSyntax"
        xmlns="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/syntaxdefinition/2008">
    <Color name="User" foreground="Blue" fontWeight="bold" />

    <RuleSet>
        <Span color="User" begin="@" end =" "/>
    </RuleSet>
</SyntaxDefinition>
```

[image]

The complete demo-project can be downloaded here: http://oberaffig.ch/stackoverflow/avalonEdit.zip