# how to add paragraphs with different formats in a richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, formatting, richtextbox, paragraph

I have a richtextbox

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="rtbReport_RTF" Margin="10"  BorderBrush="Gray" Background="White" Padding="0"/>
```

I can add paragraphs with different formats with that:

```
FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();

        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Run("Hello, world1!"));
        p.FontSize = 36;
        p.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        p.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
        p.Background = Brushes.White;
        p.Margin = new Thickness(0);
        doc.Blocks.Add(p);

        Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph(new Run("Hello, world2!"));
        p2.FontSize = 36;
        p2.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        p2.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
        p2.Background = Brushes.White;
        p2.Margin = new Thickness(0);
        doc.Blocks.Add(p2);

        rtbReport_RTF.Document = doc;
```

What I need to do is have different formats IN THE SAME PARAGRAPH. Just like

> Hello World!

with Hello normal and World! with yellow background and red foreground.

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092639/format-words-in-richtextbox?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a flowdocument

```
FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();

Paragraph par = new Paragraph();

Run run1 = new Run("Hello");
par.Inlines.Add(run1);

Run run2 = new Run("World");
run2.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
run2.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
run2.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
par.Inlines.Add(run2);

doc.Blocks.Add(par);

myRichTextBox.Document = doc;
```