# Is there a way to use a Textbox/RichTextBox with HTML formatting in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, richtextbox

I would like to have a simple TextBox or a RichTextBox with the possibility to format my text. I only need the options "bold", "italic", "underline" and the fontsize.
My text input and output need to be in html format but I can't get this format from the RichTextBox.
Is there a simple way to get the right format? Or is there another option that suits my needs?

Comment: Not sure if it's one question (format text) or three (html <---> `RichtTextBox`). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5442224/1997232) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18092639/1997232) (should be more) regarding formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I gather you will be editing in this thing then you'd have to translate html into xaml objects and back again if you used a richtextbox.

Telerik supply a control which does this. Which would be rather expensive on it's own. Telerik controls are good and this would be a route to consider if the functionality in their other controls was useful.

You could instead use a control designed specifically for html editing.

The Smith HTML editor is a very old codeplex project but plain html will not have changed and I think the code is included.

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=smithhtmleditor

Comment: I have the possibility to use Telerik Controls. I will try to use their control. Thank you for your response

Answer (score -1):

I found a nice article that gives a format bar for editing fonts via font family, size, style, etc. Please see this link, where you can download the source code: https://elegantcode.com/2010/10/26/create-your-own-format-bar-for-the-wpf-richtextbox/. Also make sure to add a reference to System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.dll. You will find it under Project->Add Reference->Framework->Assemblies in Visual Studio.

As for converting the resulting format into HTML, you can simply make strings given what UI element the user selects in the code behind's event-handling methods. So, you can make strings with `<b></b>` or `<strong></strong>` tags for bold, `<i></i>` tags for italics, and `<u></u>` tags for underline. Then for attributes like font family and font size, make strings of `<style></style>` tags, and include the CSS attributes `font-family` and `font-size`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. With this solution the whole text will be for example bold. But I need a RichTextBox where the user can write some text bold, some italic and so on. Afterwards I need to export the whole text to a "html" string. Like "<b>myText</b>anotherText<b>someText</b>

Comment: @fieRce I see. I'll give you an edit, make sure you take a look and see it later.